# Android - After installation showing two icons on the screen

Tags: android

When installing or running the app from eclipse, the app is being installed twice, or it is showing two app on the screen, two icons which does the same thing

My manifest looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.smartorderapplication"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.smartorderapplication.Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.smartorderapplication.Category"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.smartorderapplication.ProductList"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.smartorderapplication.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         />
</application>
```

I am mostly doubting and thinking this issue has to do with the Manifest file?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` entry adds a launcher icon for that activity.

Comment: Do u think I should remove both of the "category" tags?

Comment: Well, which activity is the user suppose to launch into initially? Or are both activities potential initial entry points into the application?

Comment: Login Activity should be the initial activity

Comment: Then you should remove the `intent-filter` for the Category activity.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you would have 2 intent filters in your Manifest?

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
 </intent-filter>
```

perhaps remove one of this.

Answer (score 0):

You have two activities that are specified as LAUNCHER.  Thus, two icons.

Note that if this is intentional, you can specify different icons on the activity tag to help differentiate the two.